# glassfish cluster web app deployment

Tags: java, mysql, oracle, glassfish

I have create 2 java web application, one using mysql and another using oracle.
i deploy those application in glassfish 4.0 server and work fine. then i create cluster in the server with 1 instance in local node and 1 instance from remote node. that cluster and the instances run successfully.
then i deploy app to the cluster, when i run web in browser problem happen, 
app using mysql show error "Class name is wrong or classpath is not set for : com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource" , 
app using oracle show error "org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException"

I bet the cause in this matter is connectivity. i have put mysql connector and ojdbc driver in \GlassFish 4.0\glassfish\domains\domain1\lib folder.
i have change both jdbc resource target to the cluster.
i can ping both connection pool too. 
where do i do wrong? any help appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 0):

mysql_connector_java.jar file mean missing in GlassFish

you can download [this address](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/)

for maven

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>mysql</groupId>
     <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
     <version>5.1.35</version>
 </dependency>
```

Copy the file that you have downloaded **GlassFish_Home/glassfish/domains/domain1/lib/ext/**

and GlassFish restart for oncomplete.

[reference](http://ofarukkurt.blogspot.com.tr/2015/05/glassfish-class-name-is-wrong-or.html)